# Assign a fish function to another name

Tags: shell, fish

I was trying to customize the `fish_prompt`, where I want to call previous `fish_prompt`. How do I do this:

```
function fish_prompt
    echo -n "(something)"
    fish_prompt
end
```

I tried like this:

```
alias fish_prompt2 fish_prompt

function fish_prompt
    echo -n "(something)"
    fish_prompt2
end
```

But aliasing doesn't help. It creates just a alias and cause recursion. Is there a way to assign the function to a different name (here `fish_prompt` to `fish_prompt2`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From `man functions`:

```
--copy OLDNAME NEWNAME creates a new function named NEWNAME,
using the definition of the OLDNAME function
```

So you should be able to write:

```
functions --copy fish_prompt fish_prompt2
```

and then provide fish_prompt in the way you wrote.